# Images from the site doesn't show up in Google image search, does it need an image sitemap?

Tags: seo, google-search, images

When my Client searches with keywords at Google no images of the example.com website show in SERPs. We gave alt text for every images but didn't get any results.

Now, I need to know that is there any importance to add a image sitemap for better search results?

Comment: How long has it been? It takes Google a very long time to index images. Not sure why exactly. Adding an image sitemap may help, however, not generally necessary. How important is image search to you? Generally, for most sites, it is not important at all and for others it is crucial. Where are you on that scale? Cheers!!

Comment: About 9 months. Most of the users nowadays search through Image.

Comment: Okay. I would have thought something would have showed up by now. Do any show up using site:example.com?

Answer (score 1):

What I can tell you for certain, is that adding an image sitemap into your webmaster account, allows you to tracking the index status of your images.

For example, lets say I have some 10 odd pages on my site, each with 2-3 images on them. That's around 30 images overall linked to the actual pages. However, when I was uploading those images, I uploaded 50+ images. Clearly, some of these images are not linked on the visible site.

What an image sitemap will allow you to do is give you a simple status such as 20 images out of your 50 images have been indexed. This should address your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-sharing the images on social networks. On twitter, on Google plus too. Also, make sure the image titles are relevant and descriptive of the images themselves. Replace generic names like "image1.jpg"

Answer (score 0):

You can apply structured data for your images as **[`ImageObject`](http://schema.org/ImageObject)** or **[`image`](http://schema.org/image)**.

**[Examples](http://linter.structured-data.org/examples/schema.org/ImageObject/)**:

- RDFa

  [image]
- Microdata

  [image]